# How to use `readline.createInterface` with async forEach/map?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to read nodejs input for multiple values in a loop.

I read [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) and understood that async/await works well with `for`/ `for of` as it executes in a single `generator` function and hence executes serially (which is not the case with loops that involve a callback function like `map` or `forEach`).

This is my function to read an input asynchronously

```
function askQuestion(query) {

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });

    return new Promise(resolve => rl.question(query, ans => {
            rl.close();
            resolve(ans);
    }))
}
```

When I run the following function -

```
const takeInput = async () => {
    let ms = ["shoulder", "waist", "chest"];
    let ans = [];
    const promises = ms.map(async (val) => {
        const choice = await askQuestion(`what is your ${val}`);
        ans.push(choice);
    });
    await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log("Your choice is ", ans);
}
```

It only asks me a single query - `What is your chest`. And whatever I type in the shell, it is taken as a keystroke three times.

So if I type 3, `ans` will be `[3, 3, 3]`.

> 1. Why is it not displaying the query message 3 times?

If I add a simple print statement in the map, all the three queries are being displayed -

```
const promises = ms.map(async (val) => {
        console.log(val);
        const choice = await askQuestion(`what is your ${val}`);
        ans.push(choice);
    });
```

but again, each keystroke is counted three times.

I understand that the `forEach` generates a new `generator` function for each iteration; hence, it is waiting for all the responses together- which is why it counts each keystroke thrice. Correct me if I am wrong here.

> 2. Why are all query messages being displayed now?

When I change the implementation of the `askQuestion` function by globally defining the `rl` interface -

```
function askQuestion(query) {
    console.log("Query is: ", query);
    return new Promise(resolve => rl.question(query, ans => {
            rl.close();
            resolve(ans);
    }))
}
```

The console line **correctly** displays all three queries - "Query is:  what is your shoulder", "Query is:  what is your waist", "Query is:  what is your chest".

But all three questions for taking user input (inside `rl.question`) are - "what is your shoulder".

> 3. Why is this happening?

Comment: "*I understand that the forEach generates a new generator function*" - something is off with your terminology here. There is neither a `forEach` method call nor any generator function in your code.

Comment: "*Why is this happening?*" - because you have multiple concurrent tasks that write to and read from the *same* streams.